# Display static image in wxWidgets?

Tags: c++, bitmap, wxwidgets

It's been days for me trying to display a BMP image from memory in a wxWidgets dialog, but none of my tries succeed.

First, I tried to create a wxStaticBitmap control in my dialog:

```
// in class declaration inside header file
  wxStaticBitmap *ibitmap;

// in wxDialog constructor
// MyLogo is an array of `unsigned char`
// contains the bitmap file (Yes, the bitmap file, with BMP header)
ibitmap = new wxStaticBitmap(mainPanel, 4000, wxBitmap(MyLogo, wxBITMAP_TYPE_BMP, 200, 62), wxPoint(10, 10), wxSize(200, 62));
```

I got no error, but the image didn't appear.

Second, I tried to draw the image inside the EVT_PAINT of the dialog:

```
// in the class declaration inside header file
  wxBitmap *ibitmap;

// in the events declaration
  EVT_PAINT(OnPaint)

// in wxDialog constructor
ibitmap = new wxBitmap(MyLogo, wxBITMAP_TYPE_BMP, 200, 62);

// event method implementation
void MyDialog::OnPaint(wxPaintEvent &event)
{
  wxPaintDC dc(this);
  dc.DrawBitmap(*ibitmap, 10, 10);
}
```

Now I got this debug alert:
http://img266.imageshack.us/img266/9512/wxerror.jpg

and the debugger stopped at this line:

```
// dc.h Ln 271
{ DoDrawBitmap(bmp, x, y, useMask); }
```

Anyone please point me out?

Answer (score 1):

Your bitmap is not being loaded correctly.  According to the [wxWidgets docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_bitmap.html) the `wxBitmap` constructor you're wanting to use has the following signature:

```
 wxBitmap(const char bits[], int width, int height, int depth=1)
```

So you should end up with something like:

```
wxBitmap(MyLogo, 200, 62, 3)
```

Assuming an RGB bitmap.

Comment: I'm 100% sure the image is a valid 24-bit bitmap converted into byte array.

Comment: **100%**??  In the error dialog you show the call to `dc.DrawBitmap` is asserting on `bmp.Ok()`, meaning whatever bitmap `dc.DrawBitmap` was asked to draw, is **not** OK.

Comment: @djzmo:  When in doubt, step through the wxWidgets code with a debugger.  I have found many undocumented exceptions using this method (such as undocumented items in wxDbTable).

Comment: Right - it may be a correct array, but notice how heavyd's code does NOT have the wxBITMAP_TYPE_BMP parameter? That parameter is when you are loading a bitmap from a file, but you have a memory chunk so you don't need it